# java array initializer declaration

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

This is my first time and my first question, used this site a lot and love it.
So here I go:

currently I learn Java (Java 2 SE), and in my book (Java - A Beginer's Guide (Herbert Schildt)) I managed to get to chapter 5, and am starting to learn about arrays.
I can so far initialize and do other stuff but I cannot get this code right...Why does the eclipse say it is wrong? I used the new update with the eclipse but then again...wrong!

Here is the code!

```
Class MinMax2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int nums[] = { 99, -10, 100123, 18, -978, 5623, 463, -9, 287, 49 };

      int min, max;

      min = max = nums[0];
      for(int i=1, i<10, i++) {
          if(nums[i]<min) min = nums[i];
          if(nums[i]>max) max = nums[i];
      }
     System.out.println("Min and max: " + min + " " + max);
  }
}
```

Sorry for long text, but remember I am a rookie at this stuff, here I was going to learn about array initializers

```
int nums[] = {val1, val2, ... valN};
```

Please help me!

Comment: What wrong is saying .You need to change " for(int i=1, i<10, i++) "  to " for(int i=1; i<10; i++) "

Answer (score 7):

Your `for` loop syntax is incorrect. This,

```
 for(int i=1, i<10, i++) {
```

should be using `;` instead of `,` and the length of the array,

```
 for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Also it's "class" (with a lowercase `c`)

Answer (score 4):

Use `;` instead of `,` in FOR Loop..

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
      if(nums[i]<min) min = nums[i];
      if(nums[i]>max) max = nums[i];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted has ,'s in the for loop. These need to be changed to ;'s.
I ran your code after changing slightly:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Start tmpTest3");

      int nums[] = { 99, -10, 100123, 18, -978, 5623, 463, -9, 287, 49 };

      int min, max;

      min = max = nums[0];
      for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
          if(nums[i]<min) min = nums[i];
          if(nums[i]>max) max = nums[i];
      }
     System.out.println("Min and max: " + min + " " + max);

    System.out.println("End tmpTest3");
}
```

(Changed ,'s to ;'s)

I got the following output:

```
Start tmpTest3
Min and max: -978 100123
End tmpTest3
```

So it looks like your code works